# Meaning of @Nullable java (android)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I saw this video on how to create fragments in Android and I'm unable to understand the meaning of @Nullable here. 
Also in the video (thenewboston) @Nullable was used on parameter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

But later on when I tried to create the same override method Android Studio generated this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

Can someone please explain me the use of @Nullable here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the *return value* of `onCreateView` method can be `null`.

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html):

> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can be null.
>
> When decorating a method call parameter, this denotes that the
>   parameter can legitimately be null and the method will gracefully deal
>   with it. Typically used on optional parameters.
>
> When decorating a method, this denotes the method might legitimately
>   return null.
>
> This is a marker annotation and it has no specific attributes.

You can find more details and examples in this [Android Support Annotation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) page

Answer (score 0):

Just into complete the response :

> Add @Nullable and @NonNull annotations to check the nullness of a given variable, parameter, or return value. For example, if a local variable that contains a null value is passed as a parameter to a method with the @NonNull annotation attached to that parameter, building the code generates a warning indicating a non-null conflict.

See https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**,
**@Nullable** is used to show the return value of **onCreateView** Method may be null. And also *@Nullable* shows the parameter can legitimately be null and the method will gracefully deal with it. For more information visit [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html)